# Filtering Data Frame with another column value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame with three columns (Active, UserName, Role):

```
Active UserName Role
FALSE 945480 Invoice Viewer
FALSE 945480 Maintain Invoice Streams
FALSE 945480 Maintain Payment Instruments
FALSE ClientAppAB Superuser
FALSE ClientAppBC Superuser
FALSE ClientAppPC Superuser
TRUE m002mb8 Maintain Invoice Streams
TRUE m002mb8 Maintain Payment Instruments
FALSE M003808 Maintain Invoice Streams
FALSE M003808 Maintain Payment Instruments
TRUE M003818 Maintain Invoice Streams
TRUE M003818 Maintain Payment Instruments
FALSE M003832 Maintain Invoice Streams
FALSE M003832 Maintain Payment Instruments
FALSE M003833 Maintain Invoice Streams
FALSE M003833 Maintain Payment Instruments
```

I'm trying to filter it with only the Active field of True value:

```
mask = df['Active'] == 'True'
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df[mask])
print(df_new)
```

But I receive an empty DataFrame

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Active, UserName, Role]
Index: []
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

please check datatype of your active column using print(df.dtypes), if it is of boolean type then replace your code as below:

```
#'True' indicates string
mask = df['Active'] == True
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df[mask])
print(df_new)
```

Comment: The `== True` is redundant. If `df['Active']` is indeed a boolean column, you can use it directly as the mask